How to use PolyDyne Batch API?
PolyDyne is an online quoting system and I am trying to use Batch API to lock a group of parts.
I can lock an individual part by using Patch API. However, the Batch API cannot return any expected change. Please help to check if I build the batch in the wrong way.
Here is my code:
import requests
import json
auth=('**************', '******************')
base='https://api.polydyne.com/v1'
project=109
lock=True

res=requests.get('{}/projects/{}/award_parts'.format(base, project), auth=auth)
parts=json.loads(res.text)
print('Before:')
for part in parts:
    print('\t', part['partId'], part['locked'])

batch= []
for part in parts:
    req= {
            "method": 'PATCH',
            "resource": '/projects/{}/award_parts/{}'.format(project, part['partId']),
            "body": {
                "locked": lock
            }
          }
    batch.append(req)    

res=requests.post('{}/batch'.format(base), json=batch, auth=auth, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

res=requests.get('{}/projects/{}/award_parts'.format(base, project), auth=auth)
parts=json.loads(res.text)
print('After:')
for part in parts:
    print('\t', part['partId'], part['locked'])

I get this error:
{"statusCode":500,"headers":{"Request-Time":["1ms"],"Content-Length":["89"]},"body":{
        "message": "Server error",
        "description": "An unexpected server error has occurred"
}

In case you need to read the Batch API documentation, I pasted a copy here since the link will require login credentials:

PolyDyne API - Batch
Automating large parts of your quoting process can require numerous requests to several different API endpoints. The Batch API enables you to reduce the overhead introduced as each individual HTTP request and response travels between machines.
The Batch API allows the use of the same request body structure needed for requests to other endpoints. Rather than submitting each request individually, the Batch API allows many request objects to be submitted in a single POST request.
Batch Considerations
Limited to 100 request objects per batch request
Each request within a batch will execute sequentially
Some requests in a batch may fail while the others succeed
Only one batch request may be posted at a time
POST /batch
Resource URL  POST https://api.polydyne.com/v1/batch
Required Request Headers  Content-Type: application/json
Request Body  A list of batch requests in JSON
Success Status Code   200
Response Body A list of batch responses in JSON
The batch endpoint accepts a list of batch request objects and returns a list of batch response objects. The number and indexes of response objects will always match the number and indexes of the request objects.
Batch Request Object
Represents a single request that is part of a larger batch. All headers in the original request to /batch will be used for each request in the batch. Therefore, headers are not a part of the Batch Request object.
Fields
Field   Description
method    HTTP Method of the request. Defaults to GET
Supported Values: GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE
resource  API resource of the request
Specifies the entity to perform an action. To update currency with an ID of 1 specify resource '/currencies/1'
Equivalent to the URL used to submit the request individually without the base API url.
Note that this URL does not need to be escaped as it would be when submitting without the Batch API
body  JSON request body for the request. Only required when performing POST or PATCH requests.
Equivalent to the request body used to submit the request individually
Example Batch Request
Update the exchange rate for two currencies in a single request
[
    {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "resource": "/currencies/11",
        "body":
        {
            "exchangeRate": 1.5
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "resource": "/currencies/21",
        "body":
        {
            "exchangeRate": 2.0
        }
    }
]

Batch Response Object
Represents the response of a single batch request object. The HTTP response of a request to /batch will contain a JSON representation of a list of batch response objects
Fields
Field   Description
statusCode    The HTTP status code of the batch response
Used to determine if the request was successful. Equivalent to the HTTP status code of the HTTP response if this request was submitted individually
headers   Map of response headers of the batch response
Maps the header name to a list of header values. If there one header for a given name, the value in the map corresponding to that header name will be list of size one
body  JSON response body of the batch response.
Equivalent to the JSON response body of the HTTP response if this request was submitted individually.
Example Batch Response
HTTP response body for the example above (updating exchange rate for two currencies). The HTTP response body is a JSON representation of both the responses. Each has a statusCode, response headers, and a body.
[
    {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers":
        {
            "Request-Time": [
                "312 ms"
            ],
            "Content-Type": [
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "Transfer-Encoding": [
                "chunked"
            ],
            "Date": [
                "Mon, 31 Oct 2016 13:59:19 GMT"
            ]
        },
        "body":
        {
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "exchangeRate": 1.5,
            "description": null,
            "timeStamp": 1477922359000,
            "currencyId": 381
        }
    },
    {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers":
        {
            "Request-Time": [
                "11 ms"
            ],
            "Content-Type": [
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "Transfer-Encoding": [
                "chunked"
            ],
            "Date": [
                "Mon, 31 Oct 2016 13:59:19 GMT"
            ]
        },
        "body":
        {
            "currencyCode": "GBP",
            "exchangeRate": 2.0,
            "description": null,
            "timeStamp": 1477922359000,
            "currencyId": 441
        }
    }
]

Sequential vs Asynchronous
By default, each request in a batch is executed sequentially. This allows operations that are dependent on order to execute correctly. If order of operations is not a concern, performance can be increased by leveraging the Asynchronous Batch API.
To use the Asynchronous Batch API, make a normal Batch API request with the following additional header:
Async: True
Error Checking
It is possible for some requests in a batch to fail while other succeed. Status codes must be used to determine whether or not a request was successful.
Status of HTTP Response
The status of the batch request itself must be checked. The batch request as whole could fail for a number of reasons, including missing or incorrect authorization or invalid batch request body. Before attempting to process the list of batch responses, ensure the HTTP status code of the response is 200.
Status of Batch Response Objects
Each batch response object has a statusCode field that must be checked. After confirming the HTTP response was successful and parsing the HTTP response body into a list of batch response objects, check each status code. In general, 2XX status codes indicate success while 4XX or 5XX response indicate failure. Check the documentation for each endpoint for more details on response status codes.
If a batch response status code indicates success, the body field for the batch response object can be used normally.
If a batch response status code indicates failure, the body field for the batch response object will contain two fields, message and description. These fields indicate why the request failed. There may be more information available in additional fields, see the Errors page for more details.
Failed Batch Response Example
[
    {
        "statusCode": 422,
        "headers":
        {
            "Request-Time": [
                "11 ms"
            ],
            "Content-Type": [
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "Transfer-Encoding": [
                "chunked"
            ],
            "Date": [
                "Mon, 31 Oct 2016 14:24:46 GMT"
            ]
        },
        "body":
        {
            "message": "Entity does not exist",
            "description": "Currency with currencyId of 1000 does not exist"
        }
    },
    {
        "statusCode": 422,
        "headers":
        {
            "Request-Time": [
                "1 ms"
            ],
            "Content-Type": [
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "Transfer-Encoding": [
                "chunked"
            ],
            "Date": [
                "Mon, 31 Oct 2016 14:24:46 GMT"
            ]
        },
        "body":
        {
            "message": "Invalid data",
            "description": "Invalid data in 1 fields",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "type": "Min",
                    "field": "exchangeRate",
                    "message": "must be greater than or equal to 0"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]


